# How to Add items in List of Type CheckBox and Show them in Check Boxes?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, list, checkbox

My Scenario :

I am Doing School Management System in Windows Form Application in which i have to add Classes from GUI and link that classes to section (it will show that which class have which sections) so for that i am loading sections from Sections and want to show them in check boxes so that user can select sections of that class he is adding.

Problem :

i am not able to show the sections in check boxes which will be indeed easy to select the sections for new class

What I Want :

i want that the sections i am loading should be shown in the form of check boxes.

My Code :

```
try
{
    Sections objSections = new Sections();
    objSections.LoadAll();
    if (objSections.RowCount > 0)
    {

        List<CheckBox> Sectionlist=new List<CheckBox>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objSections.RowCount; i++)
        {

            Sectionlist.Add(objSections.Name);  // here is error "Some invalid arguments"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(" No Section Found, Please Add some Section And linke them with Classes. ", " Information Message! ");
        return;
    }
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(ee.Message);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why you do this in for loop : `list = new List<CheckBox>();` ?

Comment: ok i will do it above the for loop

Comment: same error after editing and creating list above the for loop

Comment: DarrenDavies answer is correct, you must add something like this `Sectionlist.Add(new CheckBox() { Text = Name });`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that you have a `List<CheckBox>` and then you are trying to add a `string` to this list.

Maybe you need List list;

```
list.Add(objSections.Name); // which will be a valid argument assuming `.Name` is of type string.
```

As an additional note, you are in a for loop, you do not need to create a new List instance each time.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

 for (int i =0; i< objSections.RowCount; i++) {
     list.Add(objSections.Name); // I still assume this line will add the same entry for each iteration, you need to access the correct index of the array
 }
```

Comment: And new list is created in loop

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - adjusted, but the initial problem was that the List was type `Checkbox` and the argument passed to it was of a different type.

Comment: Agree, so that I mentioned `And` in my comment :)

Comment: thanks @Darren Davies for that but how can i show them now in check boxes?

Answer (score 0):

it'll be helpful if you post what the Sections class contains

```
List<CheckBox> Sectionlist=new List<CheckBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objSections.RowCount; i++)
    {

        Sectionlist.Add(new CheckBox(){Text=objSections.Name,Location=new Point(0,i*20)});  
    }
```

add the checkboxes into a container such as panel to display them

```
checkboxpanel.AddRange(Sectionlist.ToArray());
```

Comment: ya thanks @Nithin Nayagam it gives me values in check boxes, but i am geting only one value from database (first one ) in all check boxes, could you please help me that why it is doing so?

Comment: @SaeedKhan post the code inside the Sections class in your question.
I cant help without knowing that.

Comment: Sections Class is Table in Database which have 5 rows. 1st row=A, 2nd row= B, 3rd row=C, 4th row= D,  but here its show 4 check boxes with A value at each

Comment: @SaeedKhan please edit your question with the code inside Sections class. I cant help you without it sorry.

Comment: @SaeedKhan if Sections is a DataTable and you want to access each row in a DataTable then you should use objSections.Rows[i].Name